# Headless browsers stripping html source code when rendering

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs, google-chrome-headless

I am using selenium with C# and both phantomJS and chrome headless brosers for automated testing.  I have run into a problem recently and can find no answer for it.  When  certain pages are being rendered by the headless browsers they are failing to find elements on the pages.  I investigated the issue further and found that the html code the headless browsers were looking at had been stripped of all elements bar some tags in the head tag.  These pages and the tests run fine in normal browsers like Chrome and IE.

Here is the html code I am using:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form id="dataform" action="Removed for privacy" method="post" autocomplete="on">
                <p>
                    siteindicator is required.
                </p>
                <div>
            Final URL: "Removed for privacy"  <input type="hidden" name="RelayState" value="Removed for privacy" /><br />

            siteindicator:  <input type="text" name="siteindicator" style="width: 500px;" /><br />
            dateofbirth:  <input type="text" name="dateofbirth" style="width: 500px;" /><br />
            employeenumber:  <input type="text" name="employeenumber" style="width: 500px;" /><br />
            lastname:  <input type="text" name="lastname" style="width: 500px;" /><br />
            ssn:  <input type="text" name="ssn" style="width: 500px;" /><br />
            last4ssn:  <input type="text" name="last4ssn" style="width: 500px;" /><br />
            unauthorisedurl:  <input type="text" name="unauthorisedurl" style="width: 500px;" /><br />
            last5ssn:  <input type="text" name="last5ssn" style="width: 500px;" /><br />
            first5ssn:  <input type="text" name="first5ssn" style="width: 500px;" /><br />
            redirecturl:  <input type="text" name="redirecturl" style="width: 500px;" /><br />
            exceptionurl:  <input type="text" name="exceptionurl" style="width: 500px;" /><br />
            timeouturl:  <input type="text" name="timeouturl" style="width: 500px;" /><br />
            employerid:  <input type="text" name="employerid" style="width: 500px;" /><br />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
                </div> 
        </form>

    </body></html>
```

When I use a headless browser and pull the source code it is looking at I get this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Hope someone can help as I am out of ideas for this.

Edited:

Here is the c# code I am using with selenium to initialize the browser:

```
case "ChromeHeadless":
             var headlessOptions = new ChromeOptions();
             headlessOptions.AddArguments("--disable-gpu, --headless");
             headlessOptions.AddArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
             MyDriver = new ChromeDriver(Path, headlessOptions);
             break;
```

And here is where the test is started:

```
Driver.Init("SSO");
wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.MyDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
ssoTestPage = new SingleSignOn(Driver.MyDriver);
Driver.getPageSourceCode();//used to get the html source code from just before the failure
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("dataform")));
```

The test fails on the final line with an ElementNotFound Exception on the dataform element.

Comment: Can you show us your code block?

Comment: Is this for data scraping? Because somewebsites do have javascript based detection which can report headless browsers.

Comment: Its for automated testing.  As far as the developers know there should be no  defenses on the page to prevent content scraping